# Is there a solution to use 3DLUT on the entire system (Windows 10)

Tags: colors, icc, hdmi

I'm currently trying to get the entire system (Desktop, applications ect) color corrected using 3dlut or icc profile. 
My goal is to be able to use my HTPC to watch movies with color correction. I know i can use madVR with a player to correct video locally, the problem is when i try to use 3rd party applications like netflix or use PrimeVideo on a web browser.
This entire thing is really frustrating.

The best solution i've found for web browser is to capture the screen with OBS and inject reshade over the preview to use a 3dlut. But that's really not ideal and if i want to be able to watch movies in 1080p i have to use Microsoft Edge and that doesn't let you capture video from OBS.
I'm really desperate :( the only alternative i've found so far is to buy an external LUT-BOX to feed the HDMI signal to but a decent one costs like 4000USD.
I really can't understand why no OS supports full system color management.

Is there any way to render the screen over an alternative (maybe DX11 renderer) so i can inject reshade over it?
If anyone can help me out i really would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.